# Linking unpublished iOS app to AppStore

Tags: ios, hyperlink, app-store-connect

In my iOS app, I have a simple feature that lets the user rate my app. They can click a button and up will come the app's page inside of the AppStore App. The problem is that my app is not published on the AppStore yet, so I don't have a link for it.

Where can I get a link for it before it's published? Is there a particular spot for this in iTunes Connect?

Or is there just a special URL format to use (ex. )?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would register your application with ITC to make sure the name is not in use first, but all app URL's follow this format:

```
itms://itunes.com/apps/appname
```

You call it with a handy-dandy openURL command like:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"itms://itunes.com/apps/appname"]];
```

Replace "appname" with the specific name of your app in ITC (not the bundle identifier or any other means of identification).

Answer (score 9):

You are able to get the URL before actually publishing your app to App Store. You need to create the app in "Manage Your Applications" on [iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com) first, then you will find a link called **"View in App Store"** on the app's info page. You can use the URL of this link in your code.